# How to configure the buffer size for http.ResponseWriter?

Tags: http, go, buffer

`http.ResponseWriter` only has two functions, one is `WriteHeader()`, the other is `Write()`. So I figure it needs to configure in other places. Then I found this: https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go L1534

```
// 1. *response (the ResponseWriter) ->
// 2. (*response).w, a *bufio.Writer of bufferBeforeChunkingSize bytes
// 3. chunkWriter.Writer (whose writeHeader finalizes Content-Length/Type)
//    and which writes the chunk headers, if needed.
// 4. conn.buf, a bufio.Writer of default (4kB) bytes, writing to ->
// 5. checkConnErrorWriter{c}, which notes any non-nil error on Write
//    and populates c.werr with it if so. but otherwise writes to:
// 6. the rwc, the net.Conn.
```

Base on my test, the default buffer size is 4kB. I can see this is supposed to be configurable, but how? Does anyone know?

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve by adjusting the buffer size?

Comment: `bufio.Writer` is implemented in a way that slice of bytes bigger than the size of the buffer is written directly to underlying writer (when buffer is not empty there will be additional write). So typically there is no need to tweak this size. Can you write what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: We have a server that generates audio data, and it's really slow. The speed is like 4kB per 1.5 seconds. So the client only starts to play audio after 1.5s. Unfortunately, I can't do anything to speed up the process. The only thing I can do is to optimize the response time.

Comment: After some debugging, i found if i can change the response buffer size to 2kB, then the client will be able to receive the data in 0.7s and start to play the audio.

Comment: @EricYang Fix by [flushing the response writer](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Flusher).

Comment: @CeriseLimón the response writer doesn't have the Flush function by default, so I'm gonna try to wrap it up like Nick's comment. Thanks, guys!

Comment: The net/http server’s ResponseWtiter supports flush.   You cannot reduce the buffer size by wrapping the ResponseWriter with a bufio.Writer.

Comment: @CeriseLimón You are right, i can't wrap the ResponseWriter with another bufio. But I tried with `flusher, canFlush := w.(http.Flusher)` before and the `w` doesn't have `Flusher` interface. Let me try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the similar requirement and related change to `Server struct` was suggested in the past https://github.com/golang/go/issues/7467. But it was advised to add own buffering to the handler functions which needed to have a custom sized buffer.

You can configure the buffer size for the `http.ResponseWriter` by wrapping the current `http.ResponseWriter` with a custom sized bufio writer as advised in the github issue above.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    h1 := func(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
        pw := bufio.NewWriterSize(w, 10<<10) // Bigger writer of 10kb
        fmt.Println("Buffer size", pw.Size())

        strR := strings.Repeat("Hello from a Func1!\n", 1000) //just to create a bigger response

        _, err := io.WriteString(pw, strR)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        if pw.Buffered() > 0 {
            fmt.Println("Bufferred", pw.Buffered())
            pw.Flush() // Important step read my note following this code snippet
        }
    }

    h2 := func(w http.ResponseWriter, _ *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "Hello from a Func2!\n")
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/foo", h1)
    http.HandleFunc("/bar", h2)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Note: As we wrapped the original `http.ResponseWriter`, we will need to manage buffer flushing ourself i.e. `pw.Flush()`. As also mentioned in the docs.

> ResponseWriters that allow an HTTP handler to flush buffered data to
> the client.
>
> The default HTTP/1.x and HTTP/2 ResponseWriter implementations support
> Flusher, but ResponseWriter wrappers may not. Handlers should always
> test for this ability at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, Nick!! This is exactly what I need!

Comment: Sadly, the Flush() didn't flush the data as I expected. I think it flushed to the ResponseWriter, but the ResponseWriter still used its own 4K buffer size to transfer data to the client...

Comment: It worked for me when I tried the exact code written in the answer. Share your code snippet, via playground or something.

Comment: I ran your code and dumped the TCP traffic. here is what i found: You can see the package is still 4096.    `14:53:32.833985 IP6 localhost.8181 > localhost.56416: Flags [P.], seq 1:4097, ack 82, win 6370, options [nop,nop,TS val 1329849328 ecr 1588922425], length 4096 |
14:53:32.833990 IP6 localhost.8181 > localhost.56416: Flags [P.], seq 4097:8193, ack 82, win 6370, options [nop,nop,TS val 1329849328 ecr 1588922425], length 4096`

Comment: I think what you are referring to the line above is of `OPTIONS` read body which hardcoded to 4kb, see here https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L3403.

Comment: I saw on Activity Monitor on my Mac about the network activity of the Go program. I could see `Sent Bytes = 1KB` when my modified buffer size was of `1KB` with data to write `1900 bytes` and `876 bytes` still in buffer ready to flush.

Comment: sorry, i didn't mention that how i got the logs. i used `tcpdump` dumped all of the tcp traffic that connected to 8181 port. the `option` in the log is not the OPTION in HTTP request. Basically, the log said, the server(8181) send a package with size 4096 to the client(port 56416)

Comment: I don't think you can see the actual TCP package size from activity monitor on Mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236094/discussion-between-nick-and-eric-yang).

Comment: Hello @EricYang.
I'm just wondering if you managed to find the solution as I stumbled upon the same problem as you

Comment: @beingofhabits sorry i didn't find a solution to this.